# How to ignore `node_modules` folder during TypeScript build in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code IDE and typescript, how do I get it to ignore the node_modules folder during build?  Or have it build `.ts` files on save?  It is showing a lot of errors because it's trying to compile node_modules tsd.

Currently my tasks.json is

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc.
    "command": "tsc",

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // Under windows use tsc.exe. This ensures we don't need a shell.
    "windows": {
        "command": "tsc.exe"
    },

    "isShellCommand": true,

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [],



    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can now use `exclude` in your tsconfig.json file:

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
    ],
    "compilerOptions": { 
        ...
    }
}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Note it's a sibling to, not child of, compilerOptions.

Comment: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'exclude'. No longer the answer!

Comment: the link might be invalid. this is the new documentation link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html
Are you sure your tsconfig is correct.
Exclude is a top level field

Comment: @VladoPandžić and others, this option is top level; it doesn't go inside the compilerOptions.  I edited the answer to clarify (pending peer review).  Thanks to Carbosound1 for explaining.

Comment: My `exclude` options are configured **exactly** the same as demonstrated here, but VSCode is still marking almost every line of one of a dependency's source files with error squiggles. Do you have any idea why? I've also tried enabling `skipLibCheck` but to no avail :-(

Answer (score 30):

In Version 0.5 you can [hide files and folders](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates/#_editor-options)

Open *Files->Preferences->User Settings* and add something like

```
{
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/.git": true,
            "**/.DS_Store": true,
            "jspm_packages" : true,
            "node_modules" : true
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not the case, this only excludes from view hiding the folder it does not hide it from the tsc compiler.

Comment: Yup, not the answer to the question but exactly what I was looking for! Maybe you should post it as a new question ;)

Comment: This should be an answer. As stated here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22289#issuecomment-380611244 `files.exclude` will not only hide the files/folders from view, but will also remove them from the `problems` window

Answer (score 8):

If you don't supply a `files` list, VSCode will compile everything.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5"
    }
}
```

You can change this by supplying a list of the files you want compiled, e.g:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "files": [
        "app.ts",
        "other.ts",
        "more.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Nope : error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'files'.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner It's not a compiler option, it's a top level option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get you by, don't use tsconfig.json for now it doesn't support excludes which you will need. What I want is simply to compile the file you are on with options using tasks.json. For now you have to CTRL+SHIFT+B to build, there is no nice way to build upon saving yet.

```
{

"version": "0.1.0",

// The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
"command": "tsc",

// The command is a shell script
"isShellCommand": true,

// Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
"showOutput": "always",

// args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
"args": ["${file}", "--module", "amd", "--target", "ES5"],


// use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
// in the output.
"problemMatcher": "$tsc"

}
```