# How to get vscode to do the same build as what will happen with ng serve?

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am just starting my first project with angular-cli and vscode and everything is swell. I can run ng server -o and out pops my webapp! However, there are times that I know that I will be making a lot of breaking changes so I don't want it running all the time and I would like to do a build inside of vscode which exactly mimics the build that ng will do. I understand that I have to create a build task in the tasks.json file, but I don't know what drives the settings for ng so I can exactly mimic that build. Thanks!

Comment: This was useful because then I am only compiling my code. [ignore the node_modules folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313805/how-to-ignore-node-modules-folder-during-typescript-build-in-vscode) but there are still a [lot of ts options](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Answer (score 3):

Your package.json should have the following section

```
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --delete-output-path=false",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"}
```

these are the ng scripts you want to use. To call them from VS Code tasks
just edit your tasks.json to include

```
{
    "taskName": "serve",
    "command": "npm start",
    "type": "shell",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
},
{
    "taskName": "open -- -o",
    "command": "npm start",
    "type": "shell",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
},
{
    "taskName": "lint",
    "command": "npm run lint",
    "type": "shell",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
},
{
    "taskName": "e2e",
    "command": "npm run e2e",
    "type": "shell",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Additionally to debug angular you could add the following to launch.json

```
{ "name": "npm start",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:4200/#",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
},
{
  "name": "ng test",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
},
{
  "name": "ng e2e",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor",
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/protractor.conf.js"]
}
```