# Use"vscode-js-debug" instead of ng serve --configuration=[xyz]

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to use [vscode-js-debug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug) that is inegrated in VSCode.

Right now I lunch the application with

`ng serve --configuration=[Country]`

and then I attach the VScode debugger with

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to localhost",
            "address": "localhost", 
            "port": 4200
          }
```

But it's a two steps process.
I want to create an entry per country in the launch.json file, so every time I choose it and run it in the "Run  and Debug" section, the application will be launched and the debugger attached. that would be just one step.

I've tried this [How to get vscode to do the same build as what will happen with ng serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43892082/how-to-get-vscode-to-do-the-same-build-as-what-will-happen-with-ng-serve) but I could not make it work.

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it: Now I can pick a country in the "run and debug" section and get the broswer launched and the debugger attached in one step.

[image]

By adding one entry per contry in the launch.json file like this

```
        {
            "name": "Uk",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-msedge",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/CLPQV2Frontend",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "preLaunchTask": "startUK"
        },
```

And one entry per country in the tasks.json file like this

```
        {
            "label": "startUK",
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "startUk",
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "typescript",
                "source": "ts",
                //"applyTo": "closedDocuments",
                "pattern": "$tsc",
                "background": {
                    "activeOnStart": true,
                    "beginsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "(.*?)"
                    },
                    "endsPattern": {
                        "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
                    }
                }
            },
        },
```

where the "startUk" script is defined in the packages.json file like

`"startUk": "ng serve  --configuration UK"`